# Remove Automatic Page Breaks in VBA

Tags: vba

Does anyone know whether you can remove automatic page breaks in Excel VBA?  I finally found an article that says that you cannot, but I'd like to confirm.  I'm a little disappointed that this can't be accomplished in VBA.

This code, in a subroutine, seems to be able to remove user-inserted or manual page breaks, but not ones inserted by Excel automatically.

```
For nCtr = 1 To ActiveSheet.HPageBreaks.Count
    ActiveSheet.HPageBreaks(1).DragOff Direction:=xlUp, RegionIndex:=1
Next

For nCtr = 1 To ActiveSheet.VPageBreaks.Count
    ActiveSheet.VPageBreaks(1).DragOff Direction:=xlToRight, RegionIndex:=1
Next
```

Thoughts?

Comment: I'm confused - aren't the automatic page breaks determined by the printer settings?  It seems like removing them would, well, be like asking the printer to keep printing off the bottom of the page.

Comment: Are you asking how to remove the dashed lines from the screen that appear after you go to print preview?

Answer (score 2):

I think the only way you can "control" the automatically page breaks is modifying the PageSetup proprieties and column\rows widths.

```
With ActiveSheet.PageSetup
    .Zoom = False
    .FitToPagesWide = 1 'Set with to 1 page
    .FitToPagesTall = False 'Set height to Automatic
End With

Rows(1).RowHeight = 32
Columns(1).ColumnWidth = 25
```

Comment: Nice shot, man! Have the same problem and tried many other ways with nothing, but your solution works perfect. Maybe it's trick or hack, but it works. Thank you.